# Do I need to go through passport control and is the transit time sufficient? - Abu Dhabi to Sofia via Rome

Tags: transit, airports, rome, sofia

I aim to travel to Sofia from Abu Dhabi via Rome. [image: Flight itinerary]

According to the flight itinerary as captured, do I have to cross passport control between the two terminals? Also, is the transit timing for both ways sufficient?

I have checked, however, that I do not need a transit visa (staying airside) according to my nationality.

Comment: For clarity, what is your nationality? Is the trip booked under one PNR?

Comment: Because the ticket is on one PNR, the airline that sold the ticket to you thinks you can make the connection.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Do you know if I have to pass through passport control to move from terminal 3 to terminal 1 in Rome?

Comment: @Alex I misread your itinerary. The first transfer at FCO (where you change terminals), is 2 hours 15 minutes. The second transfer at FCO (where you do not change terminals) is 2 hours. My comment above about the airline's confidence remains. A brief Google search at TripAdvisor.com says that one may indeed walk between these terminals (about 5 minutes) without going through passport control.